# i have a piece of code, it instantly solve the maze, i want it to print the maze every step it makes

Tags: java, recursion, maze

i put my maze in a class and my recursion in a boolean, so everytime when i try to print it, it call back to the class and print the original map instead of the progress. do you have any other way to do this?

```
class Maze {


 String[][] (map of the maze)

   public void print_maze () {
  bla bla bla


   }  // print the maze



public boolean solve (int i, int j) throws InterruptedException {

      Maze labyrinth = new Maze();|
                                  |i tried to print the maze like this
      labyrinth.print_maze();     |and they keep printing original maze
                                  |
       boolean done = false;

      if (valid (i, j)) {

         grid[i][j] = "C";  // cell has been tried

         if (i== grid[0].length-8 && j == grid[0].length-1)
            {done = true;}  // maze is solved
         else {

            done = solve (i+1, j);  // down

            if (!done)
               done = solve (i, j+1);  // right

            if (!done)
               done = solve (i-1, j);  // up

            if (!done)
               done = solve (i, j-1);  // left


         }

         if (done)  // part of the final path
            grid[i][j] = "X";
       //  labyrinth.print_maze();
      }

      return done;
```

Comment: Can't you just print the grid?

Comment: I do not see where you update your Maze-object. So it's clear wherever you call labyrinth.print_maze() it will print the original design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is, you don't distinguish between your executing class and your object (try to make the executing class outside your maze class and you will see, what I mean). You should try something like:

```
labyrinth.grid[i][j]="x";
```

instead your code in one of the last lines, since your Object labyrinth is the object you want to change, not the labyrinth you are in :-). Alternatively you can just call `print_maze()` without `labyrinth` since you are already in one.